# Safe way to iterate over multiple databases in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, connection

I have several Rails apps running on a single MySQL server. All of them run the same app, and all of the databases have the same schema, but each database belongs to a different customer.

Conceptually, here's what I want to do:

```
   Customer.all.each do |customer|
      connection.execute("use #{customer.database}")
      customer.do_some_complex_stuff_with_multiple_models
   end
```

This approach does not work because, when this is run in a web request, the underlying model classes cache different database connections from the A/R connection pool. So the connection on which I execute the "use" statement, may not be the connection the model uses, in which case it queries the wrong database.

I read through the Rails A/R code (version 3.0.3), and came up with this code to execute in the loop, instead of the "use" statement:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(each_customer_database_config)
```

I believe that the connection pool is per-thread, so it seems like this would clobber the connection pool and re-establish it only for the one thread the web request is on. But if the connections are shared in some way I'm not seeing, I would not want that code to wreak havoc with other active web requests in the same app.

Is this safe to do in a running web app?  Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

IMO switching to a new database connection for different requests is a very expensive operation. AR maintains a limited pool of connections.

I guess you should move to PostgreSQL, where you have concept of schemas.

In an ideal SQL world this is the structure of a database

```
database --> schemas --> tables
```

In MYSQL, database and schemas are the same thing. Postgres has separate schemas, which can hold tables for different customers. You can switch schema on the fly without changing the AR connection by setting

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.set_schema_search_path("CUSTOMER's SCHEMA")
```

Developing it require a bit of hacking though.

Comment: Just to clarify, MySQL _does_ support SQL SCHEMAs, but originally and infelicitously called them "databases."  The SQL keyword "SCHEMA" is recognized since version 5.0.2 (December 2004).

Saying "USE foo" to MySQL is analogous to setting a PostgreSQL connection's `search_path` to a single namespace "foo".

Comment: Absolutely. You can even write "create schema abc" instead of "create database abc" in MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Switching database by connecting/disconnecting is really slow, and is not going to work due to AR connection pools an internal caches. Try using `ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_prefix = "customer_"` and keep the database constant.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have connections in ActiveRecord can be per class level. Its looks per thread basis because is in before 1.9 ruby threads sucked so implementations were using process instead of thread, but It may not be true for long.

But since AR uses one thread per Model. You can create different mock models for each database you have. So using answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771080/can-i-have-thread-safe-per-request-configuration-for-database-connection-and-tabl).

Code will look something like this. (I have not tested it)

```
Customer.all.each do |customer|
     c_class = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
     c_class.establish_connection(each_customer_database_config)
     c_class.table_name = customor.table_name()
     c_class.do_something_on_diff_models_using_cutomer_from_diff_conn(customer.id)
     c_class.clear_active_connections!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep the same db and tables and just have each of your models belong_to a customer? Then you can find all the models for that customer with:

```
Customer.all.each do |customer|
  customer.widgets
  customer.wodgets
  # etc
end
```